# Awk get specific word between special characters

Tags: shell, awk

I need some help. 
I have this **info.txt**

```
  [hello] 
    test world
  { gg[tester]
    }
```

How can I output to this, the only string remain is within the bracket which is 1st string of the file?

```
   hello
```

My current command is this

```
  awk '{ gsub("[]].*",""); print $0 }' info.txt
```

The output is

```
  [hello
  { gg
    }
```

Comment: Are there white spaces before every row?

Comment: yes sir. it has white spaces

Comment: Strange that you have accepted Michaels answer when he write `Presuming that the lines have no leading spaces.` and you write `yes sir. it has white spaces` in question of `Are there white spaces before every row?`, and it does not work with leading spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```sh
awk '/^\[/ {sub(/\[/, "");sub(/\].*/,"");print}'
```

Presuming that the lines have no leading spaces.

You don't need `gsub()` as there is only a single match on the line.

You could do it with a single `gensub()`, sed or even better perl but those alternatives may not be available.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk ' match($0, /\[(.*)\]/, str) { print str[1] }' info.txt
```

gawk specific.

UPDATE:

```
gawk ' match($0, /\[(.*)\]/, str) { print str[1]; exit; }' info.txt
```

This would only print the first occurence.

Just `awk`:

```
awk 'match($0, /\[(.*)\]/) { print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2) ; exit}' info.txt
```

If only for first line:

```
awk '{ if( NR == 1 && match($0, /\[(.*)\]/)) { print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)}}' info.txt
```

Comment: your command output is hello and tester, i only need hello. thanks for response sir.

Comment: @rkevx21, you only want to print strings within square brackets but not those which are inside braces? Right?

Comment: oh sorry , i already updated. bracket which is the 1st string of the file

Comment: @rkevx21, first line or the first match found?

Answer (score 1):

Your `gsub` is wrong; as you discovered, it only removed the closing square bracket.

Just exit after printing if you only want the first match.

```
awk '{ gsub("[][]",""); print; exit }' info.txt
```

The default argument to `print` is `$0` so you don't have to spell that out.

Square brackets inside character classes, which are themselves written with square brackets, is tricky. As a special case, if the first character in the class is `]` it is not regarded as the closing bracket of the class, but just as a member of the list of characters in the class.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't received the expected result because of the following errors:

1. Before parsing, you should have filtered out the lines matching the pattern "sequence of characters enclosed in square brackets". Instead, you applied the awk expression to *all lines in the file*.
2. `gsub("[]].*","")` replaces closing square bracket and everything followed by it with an empty string. This, probably, was an attempt to get rid of the square brackets. But then you forgot about the opening square bracket, at least.
3. Nothing was done in order to limit the parsing to "the first match". As mentioned, you should have `exit` after processing the first matching line.

---

Here is one of many possible solutions:

```
awk -F'[][]' '/\[[^\[]+\]/ { print $2; exit }' info.txt
```

In the command above,

- `-F` specifies *field separator* as a regular expression containing the square brackets;
- `/\[[^\[]+\]/` is a *regular expression* matching any non-empty sequence of characters, except `[`, enclosed in square brackets; the regular expression filters the lines read from `info.txt` file so that only matching lines are passed through to the following block of code;
- `print $2` prints the second record, `hello` (the first record is everything before the first square bracket);
- `exit` causes awk to immediately stop processing the input (so that only the first match is processed).

Answer (score 0):

This could do:

```
awk -F"[][]" '{print $2;exit}' file
hello
```

It uses `[]` as field separator, and then print second field (first field between brackets)